# Удаление структуры

Tags: c++

Имеется структура

```cpp
struct sNode
{
    int group;
    char name[15];
    int ds[5];
    int rating;
};
```

Создается объект структуры `sNode newNode`; 
После использования мне необходимо его удалить, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вы покажите как его создаёте. А то, может, вы `auto newNode = new SNode;` написали, а мы и не знаем.

Comment: @vegorov Нет, создаю вот так: `sNode newNode`, собственно, как и написано в вопросе. Ответ я уже получил:)

Comment: Там просто не выделено, я только сейчас понял что в вопросе это есть. Добавьте выделение, если не сложно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объекты, объявленные с автоматическим или статическим классом хранения вам не нужно удалять самостоятельно (да и нет в языке такой возможности). Они удаляются сами: у них есть четко очерченный срок хранения и повлиять на него вы не сможете.

В вашем примере ничего не нужно удалять.